# javascript object name property

Tags: javascript

This could be a very basic javascript concept, but I don't find the right answer, so asking the question here.

```
var obj = {};
var fn = function() {};
obj.name = 'something';
fn.name = 'something';

if (obj.name == fn.name) { console.log('both objects have same property'); }
```

In the above code, `if` block doesn't execute. If I use something else like .prop, instead .name, it works.

```
obj.prop = 'something';
fn.prop = 'something';
```

For the above values, `if` block executes.

Why is the if block executes for the first case, and not for the second one.Is that `.name` a reserved keyword/property in js? or something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name):

> You cannot change the `name` of a function, this property is read-only

From [ECMA-262
6th Edition / Draft April 27, 2014](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-name):

> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false,

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `obj.name = 'soemthing';` instead of `obj.name = 'something';` :)